# Using Javascript to GetCookie

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies

```
if(getCookie("response") == null)
{
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
alert("Yipee");
}

else
{

//on approve creating a new cookie
function a()
{
 var a = document.getElementById('approve');
 document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
 var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 7);
document.cookie = 'response=approve;expires=' + expDate.toUTCString();
alert(document.cookie);
}

//on reject creating a new cookie

function r()
{
 var a = document.getElementById('reject');
 document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
 var expDate = new Date();
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 7);
document.cookie = 'response=reject;expires=' + expDate.toUTCString();
alert(document.cookie);
}

}

</script>

<body>
<div id="hide">
<form>
<p id="p">Heya!</p>

<input type="button" id='approve' value="approve" onclick="a()"/>
<input type="button" id='reject' value="reject" onclick="r()"/>
</form>
```

THis is my code...I want to hide an element if a cookie exists and if not, i want to go ahead and display the form. No matter what, the form is always displayed and the "yipee" alert box does not appear.

I check with Chrome and it has the cookie called response for localhost.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: And where is your function getCookie?

Comment: And you are calling the code before the elements are rendered. View the JavaScript error console, I am sure you have tons of error messages.

Answer (score 2):

maybe instead of getCookie use

```
c_start=document.cookie.indexOf("mycookie=");
if (c_start!=-1){
//cookie exists
}
```

Comment: hey...it worked....thanks so much....but the element does not get hidden....only the alert box is displayed

Answer (score 0):

If this is a code snippet from the page and it appears in that order, then this couldn't possible work. You test for the existence of the "response" cookie and then attempt to hide DOM elements *before* the DOM elements are there to hide in the first place.

Try moving the `script` block into the bottom of the `body` and see if that makes a difference. I think it probably will.

Comment: i want to hide the element "HIde" if a cookie is present.